# Flutter - Invalid array in payment_method_types of Stripe Checkout

Tags: flutter, stripe-payments

### What I'm doing

I'm using stripe checkout in flutter via `webview` along with some other plugins mentioned below. I have used the same code for another app and its totally working fine over there. While its showing this **error** in my current app:

`{"error":{"message":"Invalid array","param":"payment_method_types","type":"invalid_request_error"}}`

Parameters which I'm passing here in reference to Stripe checkout doc:

```dart
 final body = {
      'payment_method_types': ["card"],
      'line_items': [
        {
          'name': "$serviceName",
          'amount': price.round(),
          "currency": "usd",
          'quantity': 1,
        }
      ],
      'mode': 'payment',
      'success_url': 'https://success.com/{CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
      'cancel_url': 'https://cancel.com/',
    };
```

### Plugins:

- `webview_flutter: ^2.0.8`
- `dio: ^4.0.0`
- `js: ^0.6.3`

### Complete Code

This code is basically returning a `sessionId` which then I'm using further.

```dart
class StripeServer {
  final String serviceName;
  final int price;

  StripeServer({this.serviceName, this.price});

  Future<String> createCheckout() async {
    final auth = "Basic " + base64Encode(utf8.encode(dotenv.env['secretKey']));
    final body = {
      'payment_method_types': ["card"],
      'line_items': [
        {
          'name': "$serviceName",
          'amount': price.round(),
          "currency": "usd",
          'quantity': 1,
        }
      ],
      'mode': 'payment',
      'success_url': 'https://success.com/{CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
      'cancel_url': 'https://cancel.com/',
    };

    try {
      final result = await Dio().post(
        "https://api.stripe.com/v1/checkout/sessions",
        data: body,
        options: Options(
          headers: {HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: auth},
          contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        ),
      );
      return result.data['id'];
    } on DioError catch (e) {
      print(e.response);
      throw e;
    }
  }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated, in case you need more details please let me know I will update.

Comment: Are you sure, you have card payments in Stripe activated and are using the correct test credentials? To accept card payment in production you need to activate your Stripe account.

Comment: Yes, I have activated everything and setup everything as well. Even this exact code is working for another app and here its showing this error and I'm stuck I have check all their docs

Comment: Seems like your HTTP library might be parsing the payload in a weird way. I'd check your Stripe logs on the dashboard at https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/logs 
The dashboard should show you what you sent to Stripe.

Comment: Thank you for this @PaulAsjes. The logs shows I'm sending `'payment_method_types': "card",` While my code is clear that is a `List` not a String. Any help there?

Comment: @PaulAsjes You can check this please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67785824/list-of-strings-converts-to-single-string-in-post-rest-api-dart-flutter

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me.

```
final body = {
      'payment_method_types[]': "card",
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove `"payment_method_types": ["card"]`.
A few months ago, it was mandatory to pass this field, but now it seems that it is not necessary. Here is an example of my code:

```
    var amountInt = (amount * 100.toDouble()).toInt();
    try {
      var data = {"amount": amountInt, "currency":"eur"}; //,"payment_method_types[]": ["card"]};
     
      Response response = await Dio().post("https://api.stripe.com/v1/payment_intents",
        data: data,
        options:
          Options(contentType:Headers.formUrlEncodedContentType,
            headers: {
              'Authorization': 'Bearer ${secret}',
            }
          ),
        );
      _currentSecret = response.data["client_secret"];
      return response.data["id"];
    } catch (err) {
      print('err charging user: ${err.toString()}');
    }
```

Comment: It is mandatory in Flutter still to pass. I have posted the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67785824/list-of-strings-converts-to-single-string-in-post-rest-api-dart-flutter

Comment: payment_method_types[]' : ['card'] is not workig for me.

Comment: Check your dart and flutter version. I'm using `flutter 2.2` and `dart 2.13`