# List of Strings converts to single String in POST REST api Dart/Flutter

Tags: flutter, rest, dart, stripe-payments

I have posted a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67750333/flutter-invalid-array-in-payment-method-types-of-stripe-checkout?noredirect=1#comment119781638_67750333) which is in specific to what I'm doing.

Here is the problem, I'm passing `List` of `String` to `POST` for Stripe API. But on Stripe dashboard its getting it as a single **String**

### **payment_method_types**

```dart
 final body = {
      'payment_method_types': [
        'card',
      ],
      'line_items': [
        {
          'amount': price,
          'quantity': 1,
          'currency': 'usd',
          'name': 'Some Name here'
        },
      ],
      'mode': 'payment',
      'success_url': 'https://success.com/{CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
      'cancel_url': 'https://cancel.com/',
    };
```

And this is the response on the logs at Stripe dashboard:

[image]

Any help will be appreciated I'm stuck for 3 days now.

Comment: Please mention problem

Comment: @UmerUsman The problem is mentioned, is a list of string in code in payment methods, while on Stripe dashboard its only getting a singe String

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Solution!

Change in code:

```dart
'payment_method_types[]' : ['card']
```

I have no reason why it worked this way but it did!

Comment: The data that you are sending is array. Seems like stripe is using PHP as backend for API. The type casting was taking data as string. When you add [] at the end, PHP assume the data is in array so it worked.

Comment: does not work for me

Answer (score 1):

After looking at the stripe response, it seems as if it's converting arrays into objects.
You can try using:

`'payment_method_types': { '0' : 'card', }`

Comment: Tried, it doesn't work. As it requires a List of Strings not just a simple String.